# ConcurrentHashMap#putIfAbsent but remove item if present

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've got a `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`, and I want to put something if it's not present, but if something is present, I'd like to also remove it. Something like:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
// ...
V value = map.putIfAbsent(k, new V(/* ... */));
if (value != null) {
  map.remove(k);
}
```

Except of course I'd like it to be thread-safe.

**Is there a clean way to do this? Or should I just use a `HashMap` and synchronize access?**

My understanding is that [update operations are synchronized anyway](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), and I don't expect significant lock contention, so adding more synchronization isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is not an issue, you can use the decorator design pattern with `ConcurrentHashMap` and add synchronization as follows:

```
public class MyMap<K, V> {

    private ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> map;

    public V put(K key, V value) {
        synchronize(map) {
            if(map.get(key) != null) {
                map.remove(key);
            } else {
                map.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    public V get(Object key) {
        synchronize(map) {
            return map.get(key);
        }
    }
}
```

If performance is an issue, you can implement an optimized implementation similar to the one implemented in the `ConcurrentHashMap`. for that, I suggest you take a look at the `ConcurrentHashMap` [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java.html).